# Why cannot I upgrade phpunit_selenium package in PEAR?

Tags: ubuntu, php, pear

Currently I have `PEAR v1.9.4` installed.

If I perform `pear list -a` I see:

```
PHPUnit_Selenium   1.2.8   stable
```

in the middle of the response. While the latest version is [`1.2.11`](http://pear.phpunit.de/).

I've already updated the channel using:

```
pear channel-update pear.phpunit.de
```

but still - for `sudo pear upgrade pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium` I get

```
phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.2.8
upgrade failed
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudо pear install -f pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium`.